ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1002) When connecting to Tableau
I am trying to bring in some Tableaus dashboards to python but I am running into an issue when connecting to the server.  We recently had Anaconda removed from our systems and Python 3.11 was pushed to our computers instead. However, when I try to connect to Tableau now, I am getting the below error:
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1002)

The full error I am seeing when using VS code is:
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='Tableau.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/3.19/serverinfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1002)')))

My original code that I was using in Spyder is (I've changed some sensitive date to generic data):
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_views_dataframe, get_view_data_dataframe

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


tableau_server_config = {
    'tableau_prod': {
    'server': 'https://tableau.com/',
    'api_version': '3.19',   
    'personal_access_token_name': 'fake_token',
    'personal_access_token_secret': 'asldjaldkgjalsjda;lkgjalskdj093543jdlgkj34o59lka',
    'site_name': 'Production', # not required
    'site_url': '', # not required
    }
}

conn = TableauServerConnection(config_json=tableau_server_config,
env='tableau_prod', ssl_verify=False) conn.sign_in() views_df =
get_views_dataframe(conn)


Where is viz.bcbssc.com coming from? Your config has you connecting to tableau.com. The error indicates that the TLS handshake with viz.bcbssc.com:443 is failing. That hostname doesn't resolve for me.

Sorry, the error is actually for Tableau.com.  See the corrected error message.
